# Picklist value: Customer in picklist: Type not found

Tags: deployment, picklist, error, ant

I am trying to deploy picklist values via ANT but I am facing this error for all the new values in the picklist. What do I need to add or remove to be able to deploy change

Error message is as follows

```
.objects/Account.object (Account.Customer) -- Error: Picklist value: 
 Customer in picklist: Type not found (line 524, column 18)
.objects/Account.object (Account.Sales) -- Error: Picklist value: 
 Customer in picklist: Type not found (line 886, column 18)
.objects/Account.object (Account.Seller) -- Error: Picklist value: 
 Customer in picklist: Type not found (line 1069, column 18)
.objects/Opportunity.object (Opportunity.Consulting_Team) -- Error: Picklist value: 
Customer%2FInquiry in picklist: Type not found (line 350, column 18)
.objects/Opportunity.object (Opportunity.Sales_Team) -- Error: Picklist value: 
Customer%2FInquiry in picklist: Type not found (line 452, column 18)
```

Here is Package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<types>
    <members>AccountController</members>
    <name>ApexClass</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>AccountsToDisplay</members>
    <name>ApexPage</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Account.Approve_New_Account</members>
    <name>ApprovalProcess</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Opportunity.Test Sales</members>
    <name>BusinessProcess</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Account.Candidate__c</members>
    <members>Account.Contact_Total__c</members>
    <members>Account.Match_Billing_Address__c</members>
    <members>Account.Position__c</members>
    <members>Account.Potential_Value__c</members>
    <members>Account.RT_name__c</members>
    <members>Account.Roll_up_order__c</members>
    <members>Account.Total_of_locations__c</members>
    <members>Account.User__c</members>
    <members>Account.User_modifed__c</members>
    <members>Account.test_PL__c</members>
    <members>Position__c.Invoice__c</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Account</members>
    <members>Candidate__c</members>
    <members>CountryCodes__c</members>
    <members>Invoice__c</members>
    <members>Opportunity</members>
    <members>OpportunityLineItem</members>
    <members>Position__c</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>LOGO</members>
    <members>LOGO/Appirio.jpg</members>
    <name>Document</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>unfiled$public/Sales_Template</members>
    <name>EmailTemplate</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Flow</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Sales</members>
    <name>Letterhead</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>PermissionSet</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Account Reviewer</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Unclaimed_Positions</members>
    <name>Queue</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Opportunity.Sales_Team</members>
    <name>RecordType</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>unfiled$public/Weekly_Account_Report</members>
    <name>Report</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Accounts_with_Notes</members>
    <name>ReportType</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Recruiter</members>
    <members>Recruiting_Manager</members>
    <members>VP_Human_resources</members>
    <name>Role</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Account.Sales_Alert</members>
    <name>WorkflowAlert</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Account.change_type</members>
    <members>Account.type_to_customer</members>
    <members>Account.type_to_prospect</members>
    <name>WorkflowFieldUpdate</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>Account.Final Reject WF Rule</members>
    <name>WorkflowRule</name>
</types>
<version>39.0</version>
```

Comment: @nightcrawler I updated the question

Comment: what's the version of package?

Comment: @nightcrawler The package number is 39.0

Comment: are there any record types? 
can you post package.xml

Comment: @nightcrawler Yes, there is record type. Let me update the question.